# Truffle contract deployment stuck

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency

Whenever i use truffle to deploy, my console outputs an empty line and gets stuck

Here is my config : [image]

When i run `truffle migrate --network ropsten` the console stops and it doesn't output anything.

Any help would be appreciated

**UPDATE**

Now im getting this error :

```
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ropsten.infura.io
```

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, Infura do not have functionality to unlock an account using the private key. I ended up moving my code back to remix.Although you cant work and develop locally with remix, it provides a great interface for deploying smart contracts from your meta mask wallet. No migration scripts required!